# Script stopping, may be due to onEdit() SpreadsheetApp call and then DocumentApp call

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

this script stops just at the entry of the last function : addToDocument().

Until this point all is working. I presume a problem due to onEdit() and DocumentApp call?

Note that separately, my addToDocument() works perfectly.

```
function onEdit() {
// simple timestamp -- when a single "t" is entered in a cell, replace it with a timestamp
// see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/rC6MpQDC7n4/discussion 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
if (cell.getValue() == "t") {
cell.setValue(new Date()); 
}

formatDate() // Some Date formatting using        : 'SpreadsheetApp' call
mefCond()    // Some conditonnal formatting using : 'SpreadsheetApp' call
doCounts()   // Some numéricals opérations, using : 'SpreadsheetApp' call

//At this point the scripts enter in the following function,
//and stops on the first line. Nothing being executed.

addToDocument() // Time stamp on a document using : 'DocumentApp' call
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks for reading,
Eric :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `OnEdit` is run manually it runs with a different set of permissions but while Triggers themselves have specific restrictions as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions). From that page see..

> They can modify the file they are bound to, but cannot access other
>   files because that would require authorization.

Please refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle#authorization_modes) for the authorization modes and what you can do under each of them. May be line 2 below is affecting you...

[image]

The solution for you I believe is to convert your simple trigger into an installable trigger. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forspreadsheetsheet) are details how to install a trigger for your spreadsheet. Nothing will changes with respect to your `onEdit()` function, you just have to run installation code snippet once to create an installable trigger.

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEdit')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

And [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) are the details on permissions and other details. In here it clearly mentions that you can access other services..

> For example, the installable open trigger for Google Sheets activates
>   whenever the spreadsheet is opened by any user who has edit access,
>   just like the simple onOpen() trigger. However, the installable
>   version can call services that require authorization. The installable
>   version runs with the authorization of the user who created the
>   trigger, even if another user with edit access opens the spreadsheet

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation :-) Do you see any solution to run functions "SpreadsheetsApps calls", and then a "DocumentApp call", this last fired by trigger ? My goal is to pick some values from a spreadsheet, like text strings and "DateStamping value" and to copy them in a document. If onEdit() doesn't carry DocumentApp, what could I do ? Thanks for your help. Have a nice day. Eric :-)

Comment: @Eric I've updated my answer a way to solve your issue!